# Use Duhamel's Principle to solve a PDE.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

So I have a final and I do not understand how to use Duhamel's Principle. Can someone help me setup this problem on my practice test?
The equation is $u_t-u_{xx}=tsin(x)$ $0<x<\pi$, $t>0$ with the initial condition $u(x,0)=0$, $0<x<\pi$ and boundary counditions $u(0,t)=u(\pi,t)=0$, $t>0$